# Inequality with floor function (involving sum of the first $n-1$ primes)

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

Can we somehow prove that this holds: $p_n>$$\lfloor$$ 2(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}p_i)\over n-1$$+1\rfloor$, for $n\geq5$, and $p_i$ is the i-th prime number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rosser and Schoenfeld proved Mandl's Inequality, which says $$p_n\gt{2\over n}\sum_1^np_i$$ So $$p_n\ge p_{n-1}+2\gt{2\over n-1}\sum_1^{n-1}p_i+2$$ which looks like what you want.

The Rosser-Schoenfeld [reference](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-129/S0025-5718-1975-0457373-7/S0025-5718-1975-0457373-7.pdf) is Sharper bounds for the Chebyshev functions $\theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, Math. Comp. 29 (January 1975) 243-269. If the link doesn't work, go to the American Math Society website and navigate your way to the paper. See also this paper by Sinha at the [ArXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1667) for sharper results.